# Image Upload Direct to S3: 403 Access denied

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, image-upload

I am following this guide to enable Image Upload in my Rails 4 app:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

However, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden, whenever I try to upload a picture. Googleing that issue suggested that it is because of the CORS not set correctly, but I put it in just as described in the guide.

Any suggestions what could help, please?

### Error

```
POST https://meinblog-development.s3.amazonaws.com/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

### CORS Permissions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

### .env file

```
S3_BUCKET=meinblog-development
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX
AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
```

Comment: Please elaborate more as the article provided is way too long with too many steps that might go wrong.  What have you tried so far? where is the code used to post to S3? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the acl to `bucket-owner-full-control`, instead of `public-read`.